# Apple sign in not loading UITabBarController data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` as rootviewcontroller with 4 tabs and sign in with a Apple button that sign you in and present the `UITabBarController`. However when I sign in with Apple only...data only load on the first tab.. and all other tabs are blank like a regular storyboard...other sign in with google and Facebook loads all tabs data except Apple sign in ?? I can’t fire out why.. I present every storyboard with `modalPresentingStyle= .fullScreen`.

```
import UIKit
import AuthenticationServices

class LoginVC: UIViewController, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
@IBOutlet weak var appleBtn: Button!
var userEmail: String?
var savedUserID: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    appleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAppleIdRequest), for: .touchUpInside)
    performExistingAccountSetupFlows()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@objc func handleAppleIdRequest() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }



func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {

               // Create an account in your system.
               // For the purpose of this demo app, store the these details in the keychain.
               KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
               KeychainItem.currentUserFirstName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
               KeychainItem.currentUserLastName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName
               KeychainItem.currentUserEmail = appleIDCredential.email

               print("User Id - \(appleIDCredential.user)")
               print("User Name - \(appleIDCredential.fullName?.description ?? "N/A")")
               print("User Email - \(appleIDCredential.email ?? "N/A")")
               print("Real User Status - \(appleIDCredential.realUserStatus.rawValue)")

               if let identityTokenData = appleIDCredential.identityToken,
                   let identityTokenString = String(data: identityTokenData, encoding: .utf8) {
                   print("Identity Token \(identityTokenString)")
               }

               //Show Home View Controller
               guard let tabBar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as? UITabBarController else { return }
               self.present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
           } else if let passwordCredential = authorization.credential as? ASPasswordCredential {
               // Sign in using an existing iCloud Keychain credential.
               let username = passwordCredential.user
               let password = passwordCredential.password

               // For the purpose of this demo app, show the password credential as an alert.
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   let message = "The app has received your selected credential from the keychain. \n\n Username: \(username)\n Password: \(password)"
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Keychain Credential Received",
                                                           message: message,
                                                           preferredStyle: .alert)
                   alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
           }
}

func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
    // Prepare requests for both Apple ID and password providers.
    let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
                    ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]

    // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}


func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    return self.view.window!
}


@IBAction func otherSignUP(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let otherLogin = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "otherLogin") as? OtherLoginVC else {return}
    otherLogin.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(otherLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: Please share some relevant code as a [example]. Also see [ask].

Comment: No matter where I look the code looks good but when I sign in using Apple ID ..tabBarVoewController pages not showing data at all I’m pulling JSon data and xml data on all three pages on table views